# SSRS Graphing multiple lines using each column from database as x-axis

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, linegraph

I can seem to figure out what how to set up a way to graph the following table into a graph with multiple lines.  I have the following table:

[image: screenshot of table]

I would like each row of the SRReportName be a different line and each column from ProcessingMinsYesterday and the rest (not SRReportName column) to be an value in the X-axis and the Y-axis to be that numerical value within the tables.  So it would look like this:

[image: Screenshot of intended graph]

Comment: You can represent each report by a line in the chart, just add `SSRSReportName` to the `Series` pane. However to get the desired x-axis you have to unpivot your ProcessingMins columns from the query.

Comment: Thanks! I unpivoted from the query level and graphed from there using your suggestions and that worked!! (how do I mark your comment as the answer?)

Comment: I've added my answer you can positively close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent each report by a line in the chart, just add `SSRSReportName` to the `Series` pane. However to get the desired x-axis you have to **unpivot** your `ProcessingMins` columns from the query.